# time command invoked externally

Tags: linux, command

How can I call the **time** command externally?
The command called internally is not a problem, it was enough to type **time** in the console, but I can't deal with the first one. I tried to type **. /bin/time** to no avail, however
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the proper 'time' command, you'll need to install it via apt/yum/etc. You'll need to run it as `/usr/bin/time mycommand`